# How to improve the code of mapping from List into ModelRequest

Tags: c#, list, mapping

Hello this is a mapping from a list (made by a `SensorID` field and a `SensorValue`) to a request model in which all values of the `SensorID` are reported as properties.

I did this:

```cs
public List<SensorStatus> SensorsStatus { get; set; }

public class SensorStatus
{
    [Required]
    public string SensorId { get; set; }
    public string SensorValue { get; set; }
}
```

and the model request:

```cs
public class NotificheDiStatoModel
{
    public int? qrStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? qrEnabled { get; set; }
    public int? clessStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? clessEnabled { get; set; }
    public int? magStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? magEnabled { get; set; }
    public int? puncherStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? puncherEnabled { get; set; }
    public int? bleStatus { get; set; }
    public bool? bleEnabled { get; set; } 
}
```

The mapping that works for now I did it this way,but I would like to improve the code

```cs
var listasensori = req.MessageBody.SensorsStatus;

NotificheDiStatoModel outputreq = new NotificheDiStatoModel();

foreach (var sensore in listasensori)
{                   
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("blestatus"))
        outputreq.bleStatus = Convert.ToInt32(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("bleenabled"))
        outputreq.bleEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("clessstatus"))
        outputreq.clessStatus = Convert.ToInt32(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("clessenabled"))
        outputreq.clessEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("qrstatus"))
        outputreq.qrStatus = Convert.ToInt32(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("qrenabled"))
        outputreq.qrEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("magstatus"))
        outputreq.magStatus = Convert.ToInt32(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("magenabled"))
        outputreq.magEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("puncherstatus"))
        outputreq.puncherStatus = Convert.ToInt32(sensore.SensorValue);
    if (sensore.SensorId.Equals("puncherenabled"))
        outputreq.puncherEnabled = Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue);
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay there could be more than one, as it's the same `outputreq` throughout the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your `SensorId` of `enum` type rather than `string` type:

```cs
public enum SensorIdEnum {
    blestatus,
    bleenabled,
    clessstatus,
    ...
}
```

Your `SensorStatus` class would become:

```cs
public class SensorStatus
{
    [Required]
    public SensorIdEnum SensorId { get; set; }
    public string SensorValue { get; set; }
}
```

This would reduce risk of typo and make documentation and extension easier.

Then, I would use generics to enforce a type on the `SensorValue` property right from the start.

```cs
public class SensorStatus<T>
{
    [Required]
    public SensorIdEnum SensorId { get; set; }
    public T SensorValue { get; set; }
}
```

This way you're making the data conversion the responsibility of the `SensorStatus` itself (in its constructor maybe).

And you could make your `outputreq` basically a `Dictionary<SensorIdEnum, object>` that you pass around instead of a full fledged `NotificheDiStatoModel` class that you don't necessarily fully use:

```cs
var listasensori = req.MessageBody.SensorsStatus;

var outputreq = new Dictionary<SensorIdEnum, object>();

foreach (var sensore in listasensori)
{                   
    outputreq[sensore.SensorId] = sensore.SensorValue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplified like this. Just add all the `strings` that you checked in the `Equals` in a list. Example below

```cs
NotificheDiStatoModel outputreq = new NotificheDiStatoModel();

var senors = new List<SensorStatus>();
var acceptedSensorIds = new List<string> {"blestatus","bleenabled","clessstatus","clessenabled","qrstatus"};
foreach (var sensore in senors)
{
    acceptedSensorIds.ForEach(id =>
    {
        if (sensore.SensorId.Equals(id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var propertyInfo = outputreq.GetType().GetProperty(id);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(outputreq,Convert.ToBoolean(sensore.SensorValue));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not always a conversion to boolean though.